# How to remove action Buttons from Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-9.0-pie, notificationmanager

I want to remove the added action buttons from the notification in my android app.

I used this code

```
mBuilder.mActions.clear();
```

But it is throwing this error :

```
Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)
```

Later I thought of clearing the notification using

```
notificationManagerCompat.cancel(notificationId);
```

and then tried calling a new notification with the same id. But that didn't work out either. All the action buttons remained there and when I tried adding a new action button it comes beside them.

Please guide me through the correct way of clearing the action buttons from the notification.

Comment: Maybe you should see this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922992/android-remove-action-button-from-notification Seem like which you need

Comment: That's the same thing I am following but as mentioned its throwing this error:.   Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Comment: still it worked for me, looks like it's a little bug that just shows error..